# Can I have custom post types in "Add menu items" on in the Admin > Appearance > Menu

Tags: menus, admin

I want to easily add custom post types to my menus. I know that I can do it with a custom link but I want to make it as easy as possible for a client. How do have a custom post type selectable under 'add menu items' in Appearance > Menus?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check your `screen options` at the top of the page. Your custom post types probably are not selected there. You can select your post types to see them under "add menu items".

Comment: How simple thank you. And there was I thinking I was gonna have to add something to the arguments of register_post_type().

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is the easiest one :) You are very welcome!